# My website language indicator in my profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, languages

I can edit my profile on stackoverflow.com and careers.stackoverflow.com and put a link to my website. Unfortunately, my website is in Polish and will probably be for some time, until I translate it properly.

Do you think it would be nice for an user to choose his/her website language(s)? When viewing profile it would be great to indicate user website with a flag. What do you think about it?

Comment: Or a link to a proper browser [that translates on the fly](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=173424) ;-)

Comment: Ugh, flags are a very bad metaphor for languages. There are flags that correspond to many languages, and languages that correspond to many flags.

Comment: Yeah, but it's still better than having a list of languages... or not? Maybe something different would be better.

Comment: -1, not because I disagree or it isn't a nice idea, but because I don't see the need for it. How many people have even websites in their profile? How many of those are linking to non-english websites? I think the percentage of this is rather tiny.

Answer (score 1):

> When viewing profile it would be great to indicate user website with a flag.

Well, first of: [that is bad](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/2472/40795). [India for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_India) has hundreds of languages that are spoken by a large amount of people. That makes flags a bad indicator for languages.

Should we show the language at all? No, I don't think so. I think you should assume that the visitor of any SE site is capable of reading English (excluded the language-specific sites, like SO in Language X, you can set up a different link on those profiles). Your site should redirect to the English version and people should have an option to change it to something else.

And besides that, if your profile says you are from Poland, I can imagine your site to be in Polish, so I am a little prepared.

Comment: If there is no English language version, I think it wouldn't hurt to "decorate" the website link with a brief phrase "in Polish" or similar.  After all you noted that location partly acts as a proxy for this, but in cases where location -> language will not resolve uniquely, explicit information could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to your website in the body of your profile (instead of or in addition to the link field), and use whatever emojis or other descriptive text you need there.

Therefore I don't see a need to add more functionality to the link field.

Comment: The major difference is that the website field of your profile is indexed by SEDE, while almost all the rest of your freeform profile info isn't.